# Are we encouraging answers to bad questions?

Tags: discussion

Years ago, [I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140783/180564) what to do with good answers to bad questions.  At the time, people seemed to think these answers were fine and even pointed out the Reversal badge *rewards people who are the best* at answering bad questions.

Considering the current anti bad question climate, has SO's position on these answers changed?  Most of the posts I read seem to blame the answerers at least partially (even if the primary blame is on the questions).

Comment: Keep in mind there's a difference between, "completely awful" and "not very good, even though it passes minimum standards".  Not every question that is *allowed* is a great question.  The problems come when people are answering the first types of questions, not when they answer the latter.

Comment: Dovetailing on Servy's remarks, I don't think it's possible to post a good answer to a genuinely bad question.  It might be a good answer to *some* question, but not to a question where you can't even tell what is being asked.  I certainly have no problems with answering answerable questions; if the question is answerable, then answer it.

Comment: You must also make a distinction between `good` and `correct` answers to a question. An answer can be correct without neccessarily being good; e.g. a plain code dump prefixed by "try this", or a trivial correction of a typo. The reversal badge specifically is for an awesome answer to a bad (unresearched, unclear, etc) question, which is interesting and has value on its own even though the question might not. But while the SO policies might not actively encourage trivial or lazy answers to bad questions, it doesn't really discourage them either.

Comment: the entire gamification system encourages poor/low quality content over everything else. any answer to a empirically bad question is promoting bad questions ...

Comment: For me, this question and also a lot of the answers are not differentiating between badly written on-topic question and simple off-topic questions. I also agree that off-topic questions shouldn't be answered. But I'm not that sure about the on-topic ones.

Comment: the how-to-ask reads (in my opinion) like: "If it's clear what is asked, then answer it". But just having a question that can be answered and doesn't violate one of the rules there doesn't make it a good question. And that's exactly my point: We should differentiate between questions that clearly violate these rules or are bluntly off-topic on one side and questions that are on-topic and answerable but still bad questions. Example for the second group are the 1000 how-does-the-regex-for-xyz-look-like questions that pop up every day.

Comment: @BDL the thing is that what actually causes more frustration aren't the off topic questions. The thing that causes more damage is actually the mediocre questions that flood the site and demotivate people from visiting the site, since there's nothing *interesting* to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's talk about what a "bad question" with a reasonable answer might be.

- A question that is very vague or opinion based, e.g. "recommend a tool", and not appropriate for SO
- One that asks for something complicated without showing work
- One that dumps a long block of code without analyzing where the problem is
- A duplicate of another question

As Stack Overflow matured, the standards for what is a "good" or "bad" question increased to what, for some beginners, is too high for their learning.  For example, beginners may be legitimately unable to sort through long blocks of code and identify which line is causing the problem.  Some, including those who may become decent programmers after extensive practice, also start on Stack Overflow without the skills to use Google effectively to identify their problems.  (I recently got an email from someone who was stuck for multiple days on issues of this category.  It was hard for me to believe, but seeing is believing.)

In the old days, the easy questions weren't duplicated, answers were harder to come by on the Internet, and it wasn't taken for granted that people would post to Stack Overflow.  So people were nicer about taking questions like this one from our superstar Jon Skeet, which would probably be immediately flagged as an unsuitable question today: [What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion)

(On a related note from [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts): "Jon Skeet is immutable. If something's going to change, it's going to have to be the rest of the universe.")  Jon Skeet is different from you or I.

In my recent experience, good answers to bad questions have received a mixed response.  Still, a **very** good answer to a bad question (e.g., one that lucidly explains a fundamental programming concept and includes details that a "typical" programmer may not know) is still possible and might even receive the Reversal badge.  The Reversal badge doesn't seem to be going away any time soon, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `bad != bad`. There are so many questions that were straight up garbage when they were posted, gruesome code formatting, terrible spelling/grammar, 75% noise etc., **yet these questions held value**, and were on-topic, despite being - in their initial state - absolutely terrible. Upon encountering a question like this one should - *if possible* - edit the question into shape, or - *if one doesn't have much time* - adress the author with a comment, asking him to edit his question (*and also refer to the tour, the "How to ask" page etc.*).

And then there are questions that have decent formatting, are easy to read yet are so much worse than the questions mentioned above, simply because they completely miss the scope of Stack Overflow. Questions in this category (*in my opinion*) include, but are not limited to:

- assignment dumps
- duplicates
- off-site-ressource requests
- etc

And these questions will be - if noticed - targeted, closed and deleted by the community, using the moderation tools available to us.

> Now, why'd we care if someone answers a bad question that gets deleted later on anyway? They will lose the reputation points gained, why call them out for doing so?

**Because it's encouraging users to post low-quality-questions, and these just mean additional moderation efforts, and it's getting pretty annoying tbh.**

> But those users are just going to ask a new question if you close their initial one!

Which is precisely why we have nice things like question-/answer-bans in place, to keep this site clean. **Answering terrible, gruesome and low-effort questions just undermines the general effort of keeping this site clean.**

---

Please also keep in mind that - as mentioned above - those questions will ultimately be targets of (*coordinated*) moderation efforts of the community. Answering these questions just means that the Roomba won't automatically delete the question, which is not cool.

Close-/Delete-Votes are limited, and having to use some of these precious things on questions that'd automatically qualify for the Roomba without having an answer is just a waste, and also cause for the frustration of some community members that spend a lot of time on Stack Overflow, trying to keep the site clean.

---

Regarding the `Reversal`-badge: In my opinion this is a relic from a time when Stack Overflow was more focussed on amassing content, and less focussed on the quality of said content. It's also frequently awarded when it comes to controversial meta-threads, but that's basically all it is & should be, a meta-badge, not more not less.

---

**TL;DR**: Please refrain from answering questions that fail to fit the scope of Stack Overflow. Leave a comment referring to relevant threads, pages in the help-center and so on. Don't encourage the pollution of Stack Overflow.