# Is the "Here's how it works:" part in the Help Center a possible source of confusion to new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users, help-center

### TL;DR

The fact that **not every** question is welcome here is an **important** information. Shouldn't this be emphasized a bit more in the top part of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), instead of just saying that "Anybody can ask a question"?

I don't have an exact idea how to do this, and I'm not a GUI designer, hence only [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion). If anyone agrees with this and has a concrete idea, posting a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) would be great.

Related:

- [Should the Help Center include a definition of a "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210161/should-the-help-center-include-a-definition-of-a-question)
- [What does it mean for a question to be "answerable?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238219/what-does-it-mean-for-a-question-to-be-answerable)
- [Should "Professionals and enthusiasts" be qualified in the help center?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258081/should-professionals-and-enthusiasts-be-qualified-in-the-help-center)

---

### Long Version With Links And Some Reasoning

When directing a new user towards the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) today, I've noticed that on first glance it doesn't really seem to encourage the behaviour we want, saying:

> Anybody can ask a question

("First glance" means reading just the top part, with friendly-small amount of text. The parts below, offering further explanation are most likely ignored, because people, as we all know, don't read. Here is [some random picture](http://videos.rossiterandco.com/thumbnail/people-dont-read-text.png) from The Internet that proves that, [and](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236488/231717) [some](http://blog.codinghorror.com/teaching-users-to-read/) [other](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html) [links](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/news/fog0000000117.html).)

Thus, what I imagine is implied to a new SO user that they can really ask any question. Because:

> if I, a particular user, have currently a particular question about my homework, a null pointer exception, a book recommendation, an error without any context, etc. and **anybody** is allowed to ask, then so am I.

This is of course over-explained, but in general the thinking probably goes like:

> anybody? cool! that includes me, so here it goes...

When in fact, this not that simple, as explained in the [Don't Ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (which most probably is being ignored, see above).

The Help Center was rebuilt [some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) with one of the intents being:

> Consolidate **important** information...

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The current context is: 1) a flood of bad questions ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254565/are-we-encouraging-answers-to-bad-questions), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late), [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them)) and 2) problems with closing questions ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255270/are-we-losing-the-battle-against-the-close-vote-queue), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208682/close-votes-review-im-not-going-on-a-strike), [6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/what-can-be-done-about-the-massive-close-votes-queue-on-stack-overflow)), even though partially hidden/fixed with ideas like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut), [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers), with [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270282/close-votes-are-vanishing) problems remaining. As a side note, I was unable to find any statistics more recent than [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256190/tracking-the-close-votes-review-queue-the-latest-plot-and-whether-i-should-sto) though.

At least because of these, I'd argue, that:

The fact that **not every** question is welcome here is an **important** information. Shouldn't this be emphasized a bit more in the top part of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), instead of just saying that "Anybody can ask a question"?

It also could help in a situation when you explain to a user that they did something against the rules, and direct them to the Help Center. The "problem" should be visible at once. Otherwise there seems to be a high chance of misunderstanding - i.e. "but anybody can ask, so how could I do something wrong?!".

Comment: +1 of course, but even if the Help center page will be modified, there is no guarantee that new users will read it even a slightest bit more than they (don't) read it now.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Yeah, that's a fair point, when it's hopeless it's hopeless :) However I would feel better pointing users to something that explicitly explains what is happening.

Comment: Let's introduce a Math Quiz before the ask a question page - throw there questions that people can't answer without Googling it!

Comment: I didn't know we have a help center! Who reads it?

Comment: If you press 'ask a question' it does give a summary of expectations on the left. Not sure if anyone reads it mind. But a banner in front of your nose as you post might be more effective.

Comment: @Sobrique IMHO after a user will press "ask a question" button it will be too late :) And also (I've mentioned it in the comments twice, so I'll update the question) when you point a user to the help center explaining what did they do wrong I think it would be better if the problem would be visible right away (e.g. "oooh, so they want only "good" questions, wander what that means - or sth like that).

Comment: Reminds me of that line in Pixar's Ratatouille: "Anyone can cook." - Turns out that doesn't mean *everybody*, but *anyone*. :o)

Comment: @mehow: Won't that just send everyone to math.sx asking how to answer the quiz? :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I agree that users are likely to get the wrong impression if they simply skim that.

It might be better to phrase that as:

> We're looking for really good questions about programming, even from brand new or unregistered users.

And then *really good* and *about programming* can be links to the appropriate parts of the FAQ, or even longer explanations hosted on meta.

I think if we revise this wording, we should be careful to try to not conflict with the concept of a question ban... the current wording is outright false, because we actually don't allow *anyone* to ask, if they have a history of abuse.

Comment: Nice idea! I was thinking about stating that "questions should be also useful to others" more explicitly, but that seems to take too much space. Your "really good" seems to somehow cover that. Implicitness is the price for brevity, as always :) But maybe "generally useful" could be somehow squished into it?

Comment: @BartoszKP: I'm not sure about that. When I started at SO, I had no idea what counted as "really good" in the context of SO, and I knew that I had no idea, so seeing that they want "really good questions"  might inspire me to look further. But "generally useful", that sounds more like something I already understand and don't need to read up on—even though I'd be wrong. (Although I'll admit that putting myself in the mindset of a brand-new but potentially good SO user isn't that easy, so I could easily be way off here…)

Answer (score 6):

New users aren't likely to first see the "Here's how it works" banner on the Help Center page. Normally visitors will first see this banner at the top of the site's main page. If they want to know more it's hoped they'll click the "Take the 2-minute tour" button. In this context there are no parts below offering further explanation.

Maybe it would make sense in the context of the Help Center with replacing the banner completely with a more detailed preface, but as something that's supposed to be the first thing new users see when encountering the site I think needs to be kept short and sweet. Make it much longer and you'll only discourage people from reading even that. Keep small and it can make an impression even if they're just skimming over it.

So if I were to change the "Here's how it works" banner I would only try to tweak it. Something like "Anybody can ask on topic questions". That might just encourage more careful newcomers to push the "Take the 2-minute tour" button to see what might count as "on topic".

Comment: Trying to raise curiosity seems also a fine idea! The text still would be brief but with a bit larger chance of success.

Comment: We don't allow "anyone" to ask on topic questions.  Banned users can't.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think that's a detail that would go beyond the sort of tweak I'm recommending. However it since you're recommending a more extensive change, perhaps you should you should update your suggestion to actually exclude banned users.

Comment: @RossRidge: I intentionally suggested a wording that doesn't say *anyone* or *everyone*.

Comment: So? That hardly excludes banned users. Nothing in your proposed change suggests that banned users aren't welcome to post "really good" questions. In that respect your statement isn't any more true than the original. If you think it's important that the statement should reflect the fact that banned users aren't allowed to post questions, then you should propose a statement that actually reflects that.

Comment: A link to 'how to ask' as you're posting might help too. I find I link that on the 'new posters' fairly frequently.

Comment: @RossRidge: Sorry, you're wrong here.  The original statement contradicts the whole concept of question bans; my proposed wording doesn't explain question bans but it doesn't conflict with them either.  That's the intent.  Question bans are much too complex a subject to be addressed in the elevator pitch.

Comment: I agree that question bans shouldn't be addressed here, but your proposed wording still contradicts question bans. Dropping the word "anybody" accomplishes nothing. It's not going to make a bit of difference how banned users behave, it's not going to make new users feel more welcome and it's not going to help them understand the purpose of the site.

Comment: @RossRidge: Just leave it as "Anyone can ask", and then if a banned person tries, just change the error page to, "You are no one. Sorry." :)