# Remind people that included files are part of an MCVE

Tags: discussion, questions, code

This question concerns C or C++, but it may be relevant to other languages.

When constructing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE), occasionally the question asker does not include the relevant include files. People familiar with the language will have no problem substituting it in; my issue is that it's annoying to do so. I've been making the habit of editing them in, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27081195/3920237), only if it's a complete snippet (and not code fragments). The documentation for the MCVE doesn't directly say that the program has to be compilable; normally this is pointed out in the comments. It says:

> **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** If your question isn’t about a compiler error, ensure that there are no
>   compile-time errors. ...

No compile-time errors implies that the program needs to compile, but it isn't explicit. I believe that this habit of not including the header files comes from other forums where they're considered noise, but a complete snippet should have them.

Is this a problem, and if so how do we encourage people to post paste-able code?

---

Example of some possible canonical questions that deal with the subject matter.

- [Should I include every header? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26611481/3920237)
- [C++ style question: what to #include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276493/c-style-question-what-to-include)

For larger projects:

- [C/C++: Detecting superfluous #includes? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614794/c-c-detecting-superfluous-includes)
- [How should I detect unnecessary #include files in a large C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/how-should-i-detect-unnecessary-include-files-in-a-large-c-project)

Comment: I've not often seen what purports to be an MCVE where the headers are missing, and I look at enough C questions that I think I'd notice if that was a consistent problem in C.  I've seen missing code, or missing structure definitions.  Actually, it usually works out that if the code is truly an MCVE, it is all in a single file, unless the problem is a cross-file linking issue of some sort, or perhaps a question of structure definitions.  I still link to SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) when there's enough space left in my comment (as well as to the MCVE link).

Comment: In questions for other languages I usually don't see people focusing a lot on dependencies (i.e.: `using System;` in C#, `imports System;` or something to that effect in Java). Getting back to C - if I'm having a problem with `printf` because I can't understand how to pass a pointer, how would `#include <std.io>` help the question be more clear? Wouldn't that be just noise? Please notice that C and C++ are not my forte so forgive me if I said something that is obviously wrong - I'm just trying to understand the question.

Answer (score 10):

For some mistakes/problems includes are indeed irrelevant (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087477/calling-a-function-on-the-this-keyword-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087099/sdl2-0-not-recognizing-keyboard-input) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085896/a-pointer-to-an-array-of-pointers) for example), for some other - they are. If they are truly irrelevant, then they are noise, especially when there is lots of them.

The problem is, that to know whether they are irrelevant or not usually you need to know the solution to your problem, or at least have a good understanding of it, which sometimes isn't the case for people asking questions. In fact, **many beginners don't know the difference between a run-time and a compile-time error - they are just *errors* to them.**

The other problem is understanding what [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) are. If someone understands it, they usually post a good question in the first place, with includes or not. However, from my experience, beginner programmers not only don't know about it, but even when pointed in the right direction, still don't understand it (or at least - don't get the importance of it), and fail to comply anyway.

The real problem seems to be that this site is not really fit for complete beginners and it is not stated clearly (related: [Is the "Here's how it works:" part in the Help Center a possible source of confusion to new users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270854/is-the-heres-how-it-works-part-in-the-help-center-a-possible-source-of-confu)). **Complete beginners will never be able to formulate their problems on a level we expect here, without help (and it's not their fault)** (*not saying that there are no people that ask questions on a level below elementary reasonableness* <sup>(I hope I didn't made that word up)</sup> *- that's definitely their fault*). Hence the typical implication of long comment threads under questions, if the OP is communicative.

Comment: "Complete beginners will never be able to formulate their problems on a level we expect here, without help (and it's not their fault). " I *disagree* with this statement. If you are being responsible instead of hysterical, you'll realize what kind of information needs to be included in the question. Doesn't matter if you're new or not, it's just logical. And I don't think it's too much to ask for a programmer to be logical. Obviously Stack Overflow attracts a huge audience and this isn't often the case, but I don't think you can hold their hands anymore than we are already.

Comment: @mason But many people who ask questions are not (yet?) programmers. And also, being logical is not enough when you have insufficient data - and these people don't understand all the basics, so even being completely logical they can fail to include some important information. I'm not saying that we "need to hold their hands anymore than we are already" - I'm just stating the fact. I'm rather on the position to make it more clear and explicit in site's description that complete beginners should start with tutorials/books, not SO (see the related question link).

Comment: You may not yet be a programmer, but you're expected to be logical. Putting extra info in the help information probably isn't going to help. I think the ones that read that will likely give an MCVE already.

Comment: @mason You seem to have missed part of my comment. Being logical may be not enough, if you don't understand the basics.

Comment: I did not miss your comment. I disagree with it.

Comment: @mason Well, your reply suggests that you've missed *part of it* (I didn't say you missed the whole comment...) - you say "you're expected to be logical", when I already indicated that being logical is not enough. It is a well known fact that even flawless reasoning can be worthless without all the input data. So even if a person is logical and reasonable, but doesn't know all the basics of the language they're using, they can't be expected to be able to deduce what is the complete set of all information needed to diagnose their problem.

Comment: Perhaps not the complete set. But often the most basic information is left out. I see this all the time "I got an error, what's wrong with my code?" and then they don't say what the exception is or where it occurred. The people that leave that kind of information out are going to be hopeless, even if you provide them with links to help info.

Comment: @mason I agree, but the fact that hopeless examples (of askers) exist doesn't contradict my statement. I'm saying that it is possible to leave out relevant information even for reasonable beginners, not that all beginners are being reasonable.

Comment: I agree with the answer until the statement that complete beginners are unable by definition. That is misleading. You are a beginner only for as long as one question, after this you are already advanced. My statement would be: everyone can learn how to make a MCVE. So teach everyone to include includes unless they are trivial.

Comment: @Trilarion You say you don't agree, but later, you admit that making a MCVE is a thing to be *learned*. So, by definition, beginners shouldn't be expected to know how to do it. And teaching how to make MCVE's is definitely not SO's goal. Beside, how can a complete beginner decide if an include is "trivial"?

Comment: @BartoszKP I imagine something like the following: Beginner was asked to provide an MCVE and gets comment: "This alone will not run because of missing include files. Please also provide them." or another possible comment "Your problem is ambigous because ... because you did not supply the include files. Can you do this.". After some iterations the guy will hopefully learn something from it. If there is time for such things I don't know.

Comment: @Trilarion If I understand you correctly, this would be some automatic mechanism? It sounds fine, but there are problems that are not ambiguous despite missing include files. Also, C++ is not easy to parse, so in some cases it can be very hard to decide what is being included in a source file.

Comment: @BartoszKP Like you said, it's not a trivial problem. The help of static analysis tools, IDEs and basically just plain experience all contribute to fixing include header hell. And it's a bit silly to expect either an automated system on SO's end or that level of competence from new users - after all, this site consists of users of all skill levels, and not only professionals like Mathoverflow. That's why I edited in the questions above with the possibility of having them help users construct MCVEs.

Answer (score 1):

If the includes/dependencies are not trivially to fabricate they should always be included in an MCVE/SSCCE.

Everyone creating a MCVE/SSCCE must probably have made include files because otherwise you could not run the example and could not check that it works. So if they have been made and you don't want others to repeat your own work, it makes much more sense to also supply them.

Not for every example you need an include file (all code in one c file, right order) and on the other hand all the examples of irrelevant includes given by Bartozs answer on  the first line are examples where MCVE/SSCCE are actually irrelevant. These are mere code snippets, not full running examples. So if you only show/discuss a code snippet in your question and includes are irrelevant to the problem and nobody requested an MCVE/SSCCE - leave them out.

To sum it up: If a MCVE/SSCCE is needed, include all code necessary to make the example runnable, if only to save others the time to do so. If only a code snippet is needed, exclude everything that is not relevant to the problem. Includes will not be relevant then most of the times unless there is some special ambiguity or other more uncommon cases making the analysis of the problem more difficult.