# Mention online compilers on the Minimal, Reproducible Example page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example

*(Note: This is mainly motivated by what I observe in the C++ tag - other tags may have different experiences - please share!)*

Many times a day we link people to the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) site. Yet I feel that this frequently misses the mark because "reproducible" is not further explained. Don't get me wrong, from *my* perspective it's clear what "reproducible" entails, but put yourself in the shoes of a new user:

**If you've never tried to reproduce someone else's problem, how do you know what "reproducible" actually means?**

In particular, we frequently see people paste a couple lines of code from around the location of an error (or worse, where *they think* the error is) while lacking the crucial rest of the code that actually provokes the error. I don't recall a single instance of someone adding the missing code when linked to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); it always requires explicitly spelling out in comments what they should add. And it doesn't surprise me!

I understand that the page has to be somewhat general to apply to all the kinds of questions that can be asked here, and "reproducible" is the best word to capture that, but **that's the only word it ever uses!** For a page titled *"How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example"*, it sure doesn't explain "reproducible" at all...

---

The "Complete" section in particular is where I would expect a more concrete explanation of when you have enough code. But I feel most readers will leave with the wrong impression after reading it. Let's look at it from the perspective of someone who's just been linked here for the first time:

> Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**:

*Ok, this introductory sentence ends with `:`, which tells me I'm about to read a list of things to check.*

> - If the problem requires some server-side code as well as some XML-based configuration, include code for both. If a web page problem requires HTML, some JavaScript, and a stylesheet, include code for all three. The problem might not be in the code that you think it is in.

*I don't have any HTML, JavaScript, XML or server-side stuff. Check.*

> - Use individual code blocks for each file or snippet you include. Provide a description for the purpose of each block.

*I'm only pasting a few lines, so check.* (In my experience there is no need for this point - neither formatting nor comments-per-block turn an incomplete example into a complete one - but maybe that experience is different in other tags).

> - Use Stack Snippets to include runnable HTML, JavaScript or CSS.

*More web stuff. Still not relevant. Check.*

> - DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code.

*Got it, just gonna paste my three lines. Check.*

*I did all the things listed here, so my example is complete, right?*

Unless you're doing web stuff, this entire section contains **zero** information what "complete" means. It once more says "reproduce" in the first line, that's it.

---

My primary wish/suggestion would be to **add a mention of online compilers**. It already talks about runnable HTML/JS/CSS - why limit it to those? There are online compiler services for virtually every language out there. It doesn't have to be phrased as a strict requirement, but something simple and encouraging like (wording is likely improvable)

> If your code shows the same problem when put into an online compiler/interpreter, it is guaranteed that everyone else can reproduce the issue. The code itself should still be in the question though!

already gives the reader a hard data point on what meets the threshold of "reproducible".

It might also help to include examples of online compilers (e.g. https://tio.run would be a one-stop shop), but these are probably best recommended per-language. We could refer to the tag wikis (are we sure new users can find those?) or create a list on meta somewhere. Or maybe there are other options, I'm not sure. Either way, this is not essential to the suggestion, but it would surely help.

---

Possible objections:

- *"The page is supposed to be [concise and not exhaustively complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386362/why-does-mcve-help-page-not-explicitly-address-the-providing-of-example-data#comment705458_386362)"*
  Code is probably the most universal aspect of questions on this site, and the list already contains not one but **two** items specifically for web technologies.
- *"Executing arbitrary code sounds dangerous"*
  It's certainly safer (for you) to have it executed on some machine in the web than [in your own browser](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)...
- *"Should we really endorse individual external projects this way?"*
  There are several such links on the page already, for [JSLint](https://www.jslint.com/), [HTML validation](https://validator.w3.org/) and an [R package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/learn-reprex.html).
- *"Linking to some online compiler from a highly frequented page might overload them..."*
  Indeed, this has to be done with care and some level of agreement from their end. I don't think linking to TIO and calling it a day is the solution in any case, its interface has a bit of a learning curve (depending on the language).

Comment: Even with "web stuff" you will sometimes need a different tool than Stack Snippets - for example, TypeScript needs to be compiled and run elsewhere, usually in the TS sandbox on their site. Other non-JS languages will also need a separate online (best case) compiler/runner/whatever. Going away from that, regex examples (that are relatively language agnostic) benefit from being run inside Regex101 or other similar online tools. And so on. Moving into non-web languages means they benefit even more from some runnable environment.

Comment: People have to really go out of their way to open those online compilers in a new tab. UX.

Comment: The purpose of an MRE is not to create all of the conditions necessary for reproducing an OP's problem, although achieving that is certainly a nice bonus.  As you've already eloquently pointed out, that cannot always be done in a practical way on a Q&A site.  Rather, the purpose of an MRE is to get the OP to think about his problem, to analyze it and strip it down to its barest of essentials.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think I don't understand the main point of your comment. Are you saying that listing a sufficient (not necessary) criterion for completeness/reproducibility on the page for minimal/complete/reproducible examples is not needed because the criterion cannot always be met?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your comment.  If by that, you mean "We'll still answer your question if you've provided sufficient context, even though you haven't provided all of the necessary conditions for reproducing your problem," then yes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We're losing ourselves in conditionals, so let me rephrase: I tried to make it clear ("_It doesn't have to be phrased as a strict requirement_") that "reproducible in an online compiler" is not a necessary criterion for "reproducible" but a sufficient one (_reproducible in an online compiler implies reproducibility_ but not necessarily the reverse). Yes, questions can and will still be answered without online compiler checks. Maybe my suggested wording hinges too much on formal logic (this exchange indicates to me that it does), I am open to suggestions!

Comment: There are many things that cannot be reproduced in an online compiler.  Server dependencies, for one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree, and nothing in my suggestion intends to impinge on the freedom to post questions without an online compiler MRE. Full stop. The intent is to **show** a simple option (out of many) that guarantees reproducibility, not **require** it.

Comment: I find the best if people make animated gif to record their screen and demonstrate the problem. But mentioning it *officially*? No please. Much of *stuff* is useful, but cluttering official help pages? No please. Nobody will read wall of texts then, nobody will notice *your great idea* there, rather people stop reading it completely: "Oh, it's big, I give up".

Comment: @Sinatr I'd buy into that argument if said page didn't already contain two very domain-specific items. Also, I would like to hear why exactly you think this suggestion would "clutter" the help page. Just that X is absent from the page is not a good reason in itself why Y should not be there (that argument could be applied to literally every single element of the page). Please add an answer if you have an argument beyond "if we add anything to the page, nobody will read it".

Comment: @MaxLanghof, *"two very domain-specific items"* - json/html validators? Or what? As "clutter" I mean that for C++ you suggest online compiler, that might not be possible for language X and you likely want `tio.run` to be there, so do others. Then we add my beautifully reasonable animated gif options, someone else tool for database, another guy tool for machine learning, etc... and it's all started from this topic.

Comment: @Sinatr _"json/html validators"_ No. I'm talking about the "add any XML-configuration/HTML/JavaScript/CSS", which occupies two of four points in the "complete" checklist. You cannot possibly tell me that those are relevant for more questions than a general (single point) "it really helps if you can reproduce the problem in an online compiler". This is why I don't accept your slippery slope argument - several domain-specific tools are already mentioned, but for some reason they are all web related (and thus "don't work for language X" for almost all X!). But once again, please write an answer!

Answer (score 11):

I agree that mentioning online compilers is a reasonable thing to include.

I worry that the problem becomes which ones to recommend. Stack Overflow is *large* and covers a lot of various languages.

Another roadblock is that when I tell people about an online compiler, a common response I get is "but it doesn't support X". They usually take that to mean that it's impossible to create an example and they stop, instead of gracefully degrading to reproducing it locally. Perhaps this can be headed off with appropriate wording.

> I understand that the page has to be somewhat general to apply to all the kinds of questions that can be asked here

I'd challenge this assumption. [Could we add a tag-specific MCVE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/155423) is the proposal I know best, and it would allow creating tag-specific information. This allows the people familiar with the tag to maintain this nuanced information.

Until such a thing exists, over in [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) we maintain a list of steps to do to create a minimal example (including a link to the online Rust playground) in our tag wiki. No, that's not discoverable either, so I have an automatic comment that links to the appropriate places:

```
It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't
tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present
in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce
your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible,
otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the
additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info)
you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!
```

No, people don't always seem to click on the links, but that's what downvotes and close votes are for, at that point.

Comment: Can't this be taken a step further? There are various places were tag specific help could really be useful, for example some tips could directly be shown on the "ask a question - guided mode" ...

Answer (score 8):

I strongly oppose this because it could escalate into the same problem some of the third-party HTML/CSS/JS viewers are already causing:

> [tiny description of problem]
>
> https://jsfiddle.com
>
> ```
> code here
> ```

Where `code here` isn't a placeholder here on meta, that's the literal text (so it's used as a placeholder in real questions). There's several other ways to bypass the posting restrictions linked with JSFiddle links, but recommending third party sites will increase this.

HTML/CSS/JS are already having problems with this kind of behavior, but that's without a public recommendation on the MCVE page. If you start recommending online compilers on the MCVE page, I'm willing to bet you'll see the kind of behavior I demonstrated earlier across all tags in a way that's considerably harder to clean up.

No matter how clear you think you'll make the description, you'll still end up with users who:

- Ignore the on-site part and just paste the link
- Use online services that let them add their entire projects to be compiled, and not just a minimal example
- If these services get blocked like JSFiddle, some users will paste the link in a code block, and others will add placeholder text in a code block. Some even abuse code formatting.

I honestly don't see why you think encouraging use of an off-site compiler in MCVEs will be good. Sure, they can be helpful, but what happens if the services shut down?

Also, I do need to point out that even with JS, there isn't a single mention of JSFiddle, probably because third party links can die, but I bet one of the main reasons is exactly this: to avoid off-site MCVEs that can die at any time.

I know you mean for validation, but what makes you think the users won't just subsequently copy-paste links instead of making a real, on-site MCVE? That being said, I do agree the reproducible part needs to be explained better, but suggesting online compilers just seems like a way to get more work, and get more trash on the site, even from users who may have a decent question, but who make it closeable by misunderstanding the use of online compilers and the requirement for code to be included in the question. Let's rather explain "reproducible" - make it a meta FAQ for that matter - than suggesting third party sites to host code.

---

That being said, I'm not arguing for or against the general use of online compilers. These can be super useful in some cases, but wide-spread recommendations to everyone will not result in 100% constructive use of the compilers among new users. It will not result in better MCVEs. It will not result in better questions.

Comment: My reasoning is that it's easier to repair a question that has code behind a link than a question that has insufficient/no code. I mean, we also frequently have to repair a lot of code formatting, so given actual MCVE that is inside JSFiddle/an online compiler instead of the question it's just a copy paste into the question away from being fixed. Overall, point taken though. I appreciate the insight regarding the "how will users abuse this", it makes a good argument!

Comment: @MaxLanghof yeah, but that's not allowed. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/6296561) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348731/6296561). Unless you can find a site that imposes CC-By-SA 3.0, you can't copy-paste the code from the site. And honestly, I'll rather take broken formatting than a possible license violation

Comment: I hadn't considered that, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the guidelines on creating an MCVE are not sufficient for new users, however advertising the use of online compilers may not be the ideal solution. It can be confusing (what is an online compiler? is it obligatory to use it? my language does not have an online compiler, what should I do?).

Instead, the Help page may be extended by including some advice on how to check, on your own system, if your example is indeed reproducible. Something like the following:

> Make sure to check that your example is actually reproducible. You can do this by copy-pasting the code that you provide in your question to a new, empty file (or set of files) on your computer, and run the compiler/interpreter/viewer/web browser (whichever is applicable for your programming language and platform) on that file. If this run shows the issue you want to ask about, then you have created a minimal, complete, verifiable example. If not, then you should add or remove code (such as header files, variable or function declarations, etc.) until the file reproduces the issue.

Comment: Playing Devil's advocate: "What is a local system? Is it obligatory to use it? My cloud-based platform doesn't have a local system, what should I do?". Just because a piece of information isn't pertinent to all contexts doesn't mean it should be left out completely.

Comment: @Shepmaster I never actually said "local system" - although that was more or less implied, I think the wording can be adapted to allow for cloud-based platforms and the like (maybe just changing "computer" to "system" or possibly "system/platform" may be sufficient). However, the point is, for situations where both local and online compilers are available, the local compiler is probably easier for the asker to use in order to create a reproducible example.

Comment: I did assume "on your own system" meant "local", but my Devil's advocate position can be adapted with `s/local/own/g`. *the local compiler is probably easier for the asker to use* — perhaps, but it's also more likely to have some specific configuration that will be forgotten about ("I installed this library system-wide", "I have a firewall", etc.)

Answer (score 4):

No. Because we don't really want people to submit MREs. Because we don't really want "debug my code" questions.

Questions and answers here are meant to have lasting value: a good question and answer here should also be potentially useful to someone else. Someone else with a problem must be able to search for problem like theirs, and learn from the answer(s) to the question(s) they find. That means that questions must be free of extraneous details. Specific debugging questions are useless to other people, because nobody will have code exactly like someone else's.

We often ask for an MCVE, which suggests we want a complete and reproduceable example. But this is a trick. You see, if someone starts with a large body of problematic code and attempts to reduce it to a minimal example, they are engaging in the process of debugging, and that is actually what we want them to do. We are not here to do that debugging for them. Carried to completion, that process has only three possible outcomes:

- They have discovered the cause of the problem. And therefore no longer have a question to ask.
- They have reduced the problem to some behaviour of the programming language, and that behaviour is difficult to understand, counterintuitive, or surprising. And they therefore now have a useful question about that behaviour of the programming language, which would be useful to anyone else using that aspect of the same language. Describing the problem does not need a complete reproduceable example.
- They have reduced the problem to some behaviour or documentation of an API or library they are using, and that behaviour is difficult to understand, counterintuitive, or surprising. And they therefore now have a useful question about that API or library, which would be useful to anyone else using that API or library. Describing the problem does not need a complete reproduceable example.

A truely complete and reproduceable example will require in most languages boilerplate such as `#include` and import statements, constructors and destructor and other details that are not relevant to most problems. Code snippets that focus on the problem are more useful. But those snippets  will not complie by themselves. Suggesting use of an on line compiler would encourage badly written questions.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, but the reality is that many people will/do not follow this "to completion". Should we really close _all_ questions seeking "mundane" debugging help (i.e. logic errors, not language surprises) for not including _"the **shortest** code necessary"_ (because if it requires further debugging it is by definition not minimal)? That would be the logical consequence of this reasoning. While appealing in an idealistic site quality sense, I don't see this being a popular (or even enforceable) policy.